# Add group to list using SharePoint 2010 JSOM

Tags: sharepoint

Can someone give me an example of adding a SharePoint group to a list using the javascript client object model. I was able to create groups and add them to the site but I haven't seen any documentation on adding the groups to a list? I know how to do this via c# but not javascript.

Answer (score 2):

### How to grant permissions for Group in List via CSOM (JavaScript) in SharePoint 2013

The following example demonstrates how to grant `Contribute` permissions for group `Approvers` in list:

```
   var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var web = context.get_web(); 

   var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
   var group = web.get_siteGroups().getByName("Approvers");

   var roleDef = web.get_roleDefinitions().getByType(SP.RoleType.contributor);
   var roleDefBindings = SP.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection.newObject(context);
   roleDefBindings.add(roleDef);
   list.get_roleAssignments().add(group,roleDefBindings);
   list.update();

   context.load(group);
   context.load(list);
   context.load(roleDef);
   context.executeQueryAsync(
     function () {

         console.log('For group ' + group.get_title() + ' has been granted ' + roleDef.get_name() + ' permissons in List ' + list.get_title());  
     },
     function (sender, args) {
        console.log("Error: " + args.get_message());
     }
   );
```

---

Since [SP.GroupCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee557379%28v=office.14%29.aspx) does not contain the method `getByName` in SharePoint 2010, use the method [SP.GroupCollection.getById(id)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee659402%28v=office.14%29.aspx) instead to return Group client object:

```
var group = web.get_siteGroups().getById(16); //get Approvers group by Id
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply but SP 2010 doesn't have a method getByName("Approvers") on site groups which is where I think i was getting stuck but I created my own. I think this was added to 2013.

Comment: Indeed, getByName method is only available in SPS 2013, but you could use getById method instead as demonstrated in the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I have used that method but didn't want to be stuck having to know IDs but it was pretty easy to create

Comment: I can't wait till our organization moves to 2013, 2010 seems to lacking with trying to develop client side. I'm looking forward to using the new app model.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getGroupByName(groupName, completeFunction) {

        if (groupName == null) {
            throw new Error("Group Name cannot be null");
        }

        var rv = null;
        var currentContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var currentWeb = currentWeb = currentContext.get_web();
        var allGroups = currentWeb.get_siteGroups();

        currentContext.load(allGroups);

        currentContext.executeQueryAsync(getGroupByName_Success, getGroupByName_Failed);

        function getGroupByName_Success() {


            var groupEnumerator = allGroups.getEnumerator();

            while (groupEnumerator.moveNext()) {

                rv = groupEnumerator.get_current();

                var groupTitle = rv.get_title();

                if (groupTitle == groupName) {
                    groupFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (groupFound == false) {
                rv = null;
            }

            completeFunction(rv);
        }

        function getGroupByName_Failed(sender, args) {
            alert("Error Occurred: " + args.get_message() + "\n" + args.get_stackTrace());
        }

    }
```